# How to change web.config file of a different web site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, web-config

I have 2 web applications:

1. Main Application
2. Self Portal

I want to change the web.config file of the **Self Portal** from my **Main Application**.

In the main application I get the Self Portal URL `(for example: http://servername/SelfPortal).`

How can I open its configuration file and edit it?

Thanks,
Inbal.

Comment: What kind of access to you have to the `Self Portal`? Just the URL over HTTP? Can you access the filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have access to the filesystem, you can open the `.config` file as you would with any XML file.

Using [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) you can load, manipulate and save the file.

There are other ways to open the file that are strongly typed (look at the [`ConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx), the `Open***` methods) if needed.

Comment: @Inbal - "it doesn't work" is not very descriptive. I have no idea what it means. Errors? Exceptions? Nothing? Something else? Try using `XDocument` instead.

Comment: @Inbal - When using a method you never used before, you should read the documentation. The `path` is for the `dll` or `exe`, not the `.config`.